# Linked lists: Pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c

I'm working on Segdwick's algorithms in C and trying out dynamic arrays of linked lists. I was getting a segmentation fault at `main`'s `return 0`. My focus was getting the linked lists loaded and printed correctly, and I didn't free the array of lists once that was done.

So I added the `freeList` function, and am now getting `pointer being freed was not allocated`. Clearly I'm missing a pointer/dereference nuance. Any advice?

`lldb` run:

```
a.out(3057,0x7fffb470c380) malloc: *** error for object 0x100300470: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
44Process 3057 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff7c22cb6e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x7fff7c22cb6e <+10>: jae    0x7fff7c22cb78            ; <+20>
    0x7fff7c22cb70 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff7c22cb73 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff7c223b00            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7fff7c22cb78 <+20>: retq
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
```

Running `a.out`:

```
a.out(3061,0x7fffb470c380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fbac1c02970: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
44Abort trap: 6
```

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxV 13

struct node {
    int v; // vertex number
    struct node *next;
};

// load array of linked lists

static void load_adjlist_array(struct node ***adj){
    // load adjacency array
    int j,x,y,V,E;
    struct node *t;
    int idx[maxV]; // vertex location on adjacency matrix

    // ALL edges, single way (combinations)
    char v1[maxV] = {'A','A','A','L','J','J','J','E','F','H','F','A','G'};
    char v2[maxV] = {'G','B','C','M','M','L','K','D','D','I','E','F','E'};

    V = maxV; // number of vertices
    E = maxV; // number of edges

    // setup vertex positions in linked list
    for (j=0;j<V;j++) idx[j] = j;
    // setup head for each vertex (vertex connected to NULL by default)
    for (j=0;j<V;j++){
      t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t); // pointer to allocated node memory
      if(t!= NULL){
        t->v    = j;
        t->next = NULL;
        adj[j] = &t;
      } else return;
    }

    // for each edge ('AB'), update the relevant linked list: add node to head of that vertex's list
    for (j=0;j<E;j++) {
        // edge xy: vertex numbers (also positions in idx)
        x = idx[v1[j]-'A'];
        y = idx[v2[j]-'A'];
        // load x data into t, then add t to y's adj list
        //printf("handling %c\n",v1[j]);
        t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);
        if(t!=NULL){
          t->v = x;
          t->next = *adj[y];
          *adj[y] = t;
        } else return;
        // add y to x's adj list
        //printf("handling %c\n",v2[j]);
        t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);
        if(t!=NULL){
          t->v = y;
          t->next = *adj[x];
          *adj[x] = t;
        } else return;
    }

    printf("load_adjlist_array completed\n");
}


static void freeList(struct node* head)
{
   struct node* tmp;
   printf("\n");
   while (head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       printf("%d",head->v);
       free(tmp);
    }

}

int main(){

  int j;
  struct node **adj; // pointers to adjacency list
  adj = malloc(maxV * sizeof(struct node *));  // allocates pointers to linked lists
  if (adj==NULL) return -1;

  load_adjlist_array(&adj); // allocates memory to linked lists in adj

  for (j=0;j<maxV;j++){
    freeList(adj[j]);
  }
  free(adj);

  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding this: `struct node *t; ... t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t); ... adj[j] = &t;`  When your function returns `adj[j]` contains the address of a local variable which has now gone out of scope.  Also, this looks like a memory leak.

Comment: Try adding `printf("%p\n",(void*)&t);` before the `adj[j] = &t`.  Does it ever change?  Is this what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use triple star pointers (e.g. `struct node ***adj`). They are almost always guaranteed to produce bad/unreadable results. There are alternative ways that are cleaner. Here, a double star is probably what you want.

As MFisherKDX mentioned, doing `adj[j] = &t;` is saving the address of the stack based pointer variable `t` into the array, rather than what `t` *points* to. To fix this, the function argument *must* use `struct node **adj`

---

Here is a version of your code. Your orignal code [that needs to be changed] is wrapped as follows:

```
#if 0
// original code
#else
// fixed code
#endif
```

Here is your code fixed (*side note:* don't cast the return from `malloc`). Also, note that the `printf` in your original `freeList` would dereference a null pointer, so I fixed that [without the `#if 0` pairing]:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxV 13

struct node {
    int v;                              // vertex number
    struct node *next;
};

// load array of linked lists

static void
#if 0
load_adjlist_array(struct node ***adj)
#else
load_adjlist_array(struct node **adj)
#endif
{
    // load adjacency array
    int j,
     x,
     y,
     V,
     E;
    struct node *t;
    int idx[maxV];                      // vertex location on adjacency matrix

    // ALL edges, single way (combinations)
    char v1[maxV] = { 'A', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'F', 'A', 'G' };
    char v2[maxV] = { 'G', 'B', 'C', 'M', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'D', 'D', 'I', 'E', 'F', 'E' };

    V = maxV;                           // number of vertices
    E = maxV;                           // number of edges

    // setup vertex positions in linked list
    for (j = 0; j < V; j++)
        idx[j] = j;
    // setup head for each vertex (vertex connected to NULL by default)
    for (j = 0; j < V; j++) {
        t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);  // pointer to allocated node memory
        if (t != NULL) {
            t->v = j;
            t->next = NULL;
#if 0
            adj[j] = &t;
#else
            adj[j] = t;
#endif
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    // for each edge ('AB'), update the relevant linked list: add node to head of that vertex's list
    for (j = 0; j < E; j++) {
        // edge xy: vertex numbers (also positions in idx)
        x = idx[v1[j] - 'A'];
        y = idx[v2[j] - 'A'];
        // load x data into t, then add t to y's adj list
        // printf("handling %c\n",v1[j]);
        t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);
        if (t != NULL) {
            t->v = x;
#if 0
            t->next = *adj[y];
#else
            t->next = adj[y];
#endif
#if 0
            *adj[y] = t;
#else
            adj[y] = t;
#endif
        }
        else
            return;
        // add y to x's adj list
        // printf("handling %c\n",v2[j]);
        t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);
        if (t != NULL) {
            t->v = y;
#if 0
            t->next = *adj[x];
#else
            t->next = adj[x];
#endif
#if 0
            *adj[x] = t;
#else
            adj[x] = t;
#endif
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    printf("load_adjlist_array completed\n");
}

static void
freeList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *tmp;

    printf("\n");
    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        head = tmp->next;
        printf("%d", tmp->v);
        free(tmp);
    }

}

int
main()
{

    int j;
#if 0
    struct node **adj;                  // pointers to adjacency list
#else
    struct node **adj;                  // pointers to adjacency list
#endif

    adj = malloc(maxV * sizeof(struct node *)); // allocates pointers to linked lists
    if (adj == NULL)
        return -1;

#if 0
    load_adjlist_array(&adj);           // allocates memory to linked lists in adj
#else
    load_adjlist_array(adj);            // allocates memory to linked lists in adj
#endif

    for (j = 0; j < maxV; j++) {
        freeList(adj[j]);
    }
    free(adj);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a cleaned up version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxV 13

struct node {
    int v;                              // vertex number
    struct node *next;
};

// load array of linked lists

static void
load_adjlist_array(struct node **adj)
{
    // load adjacency array
    int j,
     x,
     y,
     V,
     E;
    struct node *t;
    int idx[maxV];                      // vertex location on adjacency matrix

    // ALL edges, single way (combinations)
    char v1[maxV] = { 'A', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'F', 'A', 'G' };
    char v2[maxV] = { 'G', 'B', 'C', 'M', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'D', 'D', 'I', 'E', 'F', 'E' };

    V = maxV;                           // number of vertices
    E = maxV;                           // number of edges

    // setup vertex positions in linked list
    for (j = 0; j < V; j++)
        idx[j] = j;
    // setup head for each vertex (vertex connected to NULL by default)
    for (j = 0; j < V; j++) {
        t = malloc(sizeof *t);  // pointer to allocated node memory
        if (t != NULL) {
            t->v = j;
            t->next = NULL;
            adj[j] = t;
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    // for each edge ('AB'), update the relevant linked list: add node to head of that vertex's list
    for (j = 0; j < E; j++) {
        // edge xy: vertex numbers (also positions in idx)
        x = idx[v1[j] - 'A'];
        y = idx[v2[j] - 'A'];
        // load x data into t, then add t to y's adj list
        // printf("handling %c\n",v1[j]);
        t = malloc(sizeof *t);
        if (t != NULL) {
            t->v = x;
            t->next = adj[y];
            adj[y] = t;
        }
        else
            return;
        // add y to x's adj list
        // printf("handling %c\n",v2[j]);
        t = malloc(sizeof *t);
        if (t != NULL) {
            t->v = y;
            t->next = adj[x];
            adj[x] = t;
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    printf("load_adjlist_array completed\n");
}

static void
freeList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *tmp;

    printf("\n");
    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        head = tmp->next;
        printf("%d", tmp->v);
        free(tmp);
    }

}

int
main()
{

    int j;
    struct node **adj;                  // pointers to adjacency list

    // allocates pointers to linked lists
    adj = malloc(maxV * sizeof(struct node *));
    if (adj == NULL)
        return -1;

    load_adjlist_array(adj);            // allocates memory to linked lists in adj

    for (j = 0; j < maxV; j++) {
        freeList(adj[j]);
    }
    free(adj);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the output of the fixed up program:

```
load_adjlist_array completed

52160
01
02
543
6534
0435
406
87
78
1011129
910
91211
91112
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean code, tips & clarifications.